# Jquery .load() function after session time out

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, spring-security

the problem:
i have a button on a page, which activates a JQuery script:

`function loadPage(elementId, typeId) {
    alert("loadPage/" + typeId);
    $("#" + elementId).load("loadPage/" + typeId);
}`

But when i click it after session has been expired i'am not redirected to login page but login page loaded inside the parent page which is not what i need.

[here is a screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbLU0.png)

*Security config:*

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern='/login' access='permitAll' />
    <intercept-url pattern='/**' access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                default-target-url="/projects"
                username-parameter="email" password-parameter="password"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"/>
</http>

<security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userServiceImpl">
        <!--<password-encoder ref="encoder"></password-encoder>-->
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

*Login controller:*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage() {
    return "login";
}
```

Right now i have no idea hot to deal with it. How can i change this behavior to redirection to login page?

Comment: You need to check if the session has ended and redirect to the login page if it has. Otherwise it will just keep loading the login page into the #id.

If the session returns a error code, you can use that.

Comment: @Anuga , yes i'm thinking about check before .load(), but i don't know how to do it yet. will appriciate any help in this regard

Comment: Don't you have a session cookie? you should have? you could check that, then if it's still "active" you could run the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you try to load the content into a div or span and the login page is a "whole" page on it's own.

You could check via js/jquery if the content is the loginpage, with a flag or something and do a redirect to the loginpage after on.

Put something like

```
<!-- loginpageflag -->
```

into your loginpage and do something like

```
function loadPage(elementId, typeId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "loadPage/" + typeId, 
        type: "GET", 
        dataType: "html", 
        success: function (data) { 
            alert(data);
            if(data.indexOf("loginpageflag") > -1) { 
                window.location.replace("/login"); 
            } 
            var selection = $("#" + elementId); 
            selection.empty(); 
            selection.append(data); 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: yes, i understand the problem. do you know is it possible to check before .load() function if i'm still logged in? by js or somehow...

Comment: i've put some code into my answer aswell.. something like the above should do :)

Comment: strange, but every time the index is -1. `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- loginPageFlag -->`. Probably commented lines are not considered. now i put the flag inside of hidden <div>. will see..

Comment: take a look.. here it works like a charme: https://jsfiddle.net/ujj5u6h5/2/

Comment: when i click the button first time the index is -1, and login page inserted into parent page, but when i click second time the index is not -1 anymore and i am redirected to login...something is not considered in this solution. may be some kind of page data refresh needs to be done?

Comment: hm. perhaps loading the content  isn't ready when you check it via indexOf(). can you try to put in in a `setTimeout(function(){ ... }, 100);`

Comment: i ended up with following code:
`function loadPage(elementId, typeId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "loadPage/" + typeId,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            if(data.indexOf("loginpageflag") > -1){
                window.location.replace("/login");
            }
            var selection = $("#" + elementId);
            selection.empty();
            selection.append(data);
        }
    })
}`

Comment: alrigth.. nice you got it to work :) i've edited my answer with the final piece of code.